# Cannot load Xdebug, as PHP was built with API NTS debug

Tags: macos, homebrew, xdebug, php-7

I installed php70 and php70-xdebug using `brew`.

```
brew install php70
brew install php70-xdebug
```

`php -v` returns this error:

> Cannot load Xdebug - it was built with configuration API320151012,NTS,
>   whereas running engine is API320151012,NTS,debug

I can't figure out how to pass `--disable-debug` to the compiler, brew uses preconfigured formula (https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-php), and doesn't allow to set this option.

The problem is: xdebug formula has `--disable-debug`, and php70 formula has an option `--with-debug`, but even if you don't use this argument, it appends `--enable-debug` to the configure command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a workaround, it isn't perfect to do that, but it works!

1. Edit the Formula with `brew edit php70-xdebug` and add `--enable-debug` to the configure command :

   ```
   system "./configure", "--prefix=#{prefix}",
                     phpconfig,
                     "--disable-dependency-tracking",
                     "--enable-xdebug",
                     "--enable-debug"
   ```
2. Recompile the library

   ```
   brew reinstall php70-xdebug --build-from-source
   ```

Same thing works with `php70-opcache` as well.